# What is the difference between 一切， 都 and 全部？

Tags: usage, difference

What is the difference between 一切， 都 and 全部？ Can you give some examples where the difference would be visible?

Answer (score 3):

> [一切](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/5511/) : all; everything; every; all sorts
>
> [全部](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/1012/) : entire; all; whole; total
>
> [所有](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/2507/) : all; whatever there is

~

> '一切' describes everything that's known or unknown, without confine.
>
> For example, "一切後果由我來負";  (All consequence will be handled by me).
>
> *You don't necessary know what exactly they are, there's no confine*

~

> '全部' describes everything that's known or in a confine
>
> Examples:
>
> 人體裡的全部器官 (all the organs in human body)- *You know what they are exactly; and it is in the confine of a human body*
>
> 圖書館裡的全部書籍 (All the books in the library)- *In the confine of the library*

所有 is more general, it can replace either 一切 or 全部

- **所有**後果由我來負 = **一切**後果由我來負
- 人體裡的**所有**器官 = 人體裡的**全部**器官
- 圖書館裡的**所有**書籍 = 圖書館裡的**全部**書籍

> [都](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/329/) is an adverb for [all; both; without exception]
>
> Example:
>
> 圖書館裡的所有書籍**都**要盖章 - Every book in the library **all** needed to be stamped

一切 can be a noun for "Everything"

全部 can be a noun for "the whole thing/ the entire thing/ every parts"

[所有](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/2507/) is strictly an adjective  when it means 'all/ every'.  But it carries other meanings too. (see link)

Answer (score 2):

都 is an adverb meaning: (is) all:

一切都准备好了。 
Everything is ready.

一切 is a noun meaning everything:

一切由他负责。 
He's responsible for everything.

全部 is a noun meaning (the) whole (part):

他知道全部真相。 
He knows the whole truth.

都 being an adverb is usually found at the end of words like 一切 and 全部3

一切都
it all is

全部都
the whole (thing) is